# python pandas averaging columns to produce new ones

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following data, displaying the hours worked per week for employees at a company:

```
name       week 1     week 2      week 3     week 4...

joey       20         15           35         10
thomas     20         10           25         15
mark       30         20           25         10
sal        25         25           15         20
amy        25         30           20         10
```

Assume the data carries on in the same for 100+ weeks.

What I want to produce is a biweekly average of hours for each employee,
so the average hours worked over two weeks. Shown in the following DataFrame:

```
name       weeks 1-2      weeks 2-4...      

joey         17.5           22.5           
thomas       15             20           
mark         25             17.5         
sal          25             17.5           
amy          27.5           15
```

How could I make this work? Trying out iterating right now but I'm stuck.

Comment: _Assume the data carries on in the same for 100+ weeks._ That sounds like a lot, wow many columns are you going to end up with?

Comment: starting with 192 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 2): 
    df[f'weeks {i+1}-{i+2}'] = df.iloc[:, i:i+1].mean(axis=1)
```

This code basically iterates through the amount of columns, taking a step of size 2. Then it selects the column indicated by the current iteration (variable `i`) and the following column (`i+1`), averages these two, and stores in a new column.

It assumes columns are properly ordered.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks. Would you mind explaining how the: df[f'weeks {i+1}-{i+2}'] part works? what does the 'f' before the string do? I have slightly different data then presented in the problem and need to name the columns differently so it would be helpful to know how to use this feature. Thanks!

Comment: Those are called `f-strings` and were introduced in Python's 3.6 version. They provide a way to interpolate variables inside strings. What's happening, in that case, is the same as what would happen with the following string concatenation: `'weeks ' + str(i+1) + '-' + str(i+2)`. You can find out more about them here for instance: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/